# Are MySQL error codes returned by mysqli_errno() consistent?

Tags: php, mysql, error-code

I'm wondering if MySQL error codes returned by [`mysqli_errno()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) are consistent, or in other words, can they change in the next release of MySQL?

I was doing something like this:

```
$errNo = mysqli_errno($link);
if($errNo == 1146)
{
    //Table doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Probably not. But you can set this codes to static helper or constant, so if something would be changed you can fix just one helper or constant.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's possible that error codes for some conditions might change. But it would be unlikely, and I'm sure MySQL has incentive to avoid breaking everyone's code.

If you want to be sure, there are at least two straightforward methods to do so:

1. **Read the documentation!** Error codes for each version of MySQL are listed in a reference page. You can select the version of the documentation you're reading by changing the selector in the upper right corner.

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html
2. **Empirical testing!** Try the operation in the MySQL client and see which error code is output. Do this before any upgrade you are concerned about.

   ```
   mysql> select * from table_that_does_not_exist;
   ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.table_that_does_not_exist' doesn't exist

   mysql> select version();
   +---------------+
   | version()     |
   +---------------+
   | 5.7.27-30-log |
   +---------------+
   ```

   Then test another version:

   ```
   mysql> select * from table_that_does_not_exist;
   ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.table_that_does_not_exist' doesn't exist

   mysql> select version();
   +-----------+
   | version() |
   +-----------+
   | 8.0.17-8  |
   +-----------+
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect these codes to ever change, because undoubtedly there's an unknown amount of code out there which did use hard-coded constants like `43`.  But *you* should use constants.  (See for example:  https://github.com/VividCortex/mysqlerr.)  Every programming language that has a MySQL interface also provides constants.

However, notice that over time some error-codes do become *obsolete* because of changes in how the underlying MySQL system works.  Consider the following quote from the above web-site:

> Notice that some constants were renamed in later versions of MySQL, because they became obsolete. (In case you wonder: the names here match the symbols MySQL uses in source code.) Obsolete names haven't been changed in this package to avoid breaking code, but you should no longer be using them in applications.

... to which I would further add, *"any logic in your application which now tests for any of those obsolete constants probably also demands further changes now."*  If the MySQL team renamed a constant, they probably did much more.

Obviously, if you have used constants as you should, it will make it easier to find these places in your code.  (Especially important to the people who follow after you once you've moved on ...)  You should always review the release-notes in every new version of MySQL (or any other system upon which your code depends, including the language itself).  Features are sometimes declared to be "deprecated," and it's your responsibility to keep your applications up-to-date with that.